# simple about php upload file

Tags: php, upload

I'm using the built-in PHP function `copy()` to upload the image or file to my host.

Therefore, I wonder why the file must move to the temp file before upload to the destination?

Comment: Do you want PHP to store temporary files (pending and aborted uploads) in your destination directory? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the file must move to the temp file before upload to the destination?

This is just how file uploads are managed by PHP; the posted body from the client (web browser) is passed from the web server to PHP in `multipart/form-data` format, which is then decoded.

Because this process happens before your script runs, PHP stores the files in a temporary location, defined by [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir).

Btw, it's recommended to use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) instead of `copy()`; it makes sure the file was actually uploaded as part of the current request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use [Move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). You can not upload file with copy, if you are uploading files with file tag in your form.

With move_uploaded_file you have advantage of error handling,size restriction, file type restriction and many more. Just read the link.
syntax is:

```
move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);
```

Comment: It's a matter of server configuration whether `copy()` can be used.

Comment: but with move_uploaded_file we can handle error, file upload restriction,upload size and many more things ,that can not be done with copy.

Comment: Upload size restrictions are applied *before* a copy can take place though iirc. Fact remains that `copy()` is possible, albeit not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

When we use file field in a html form, it save the files into temporary folder. 
You need to move_upload_fle function to copy the file from temporary directory to your destination directory.

```
move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);
```